# Vue determine if component has mounted

Tags: vue.js

Is there a built-in way of determining if the component has mounted in Vue?

I know I could just do `mounted() { this.hasMounted = true; }` but I would like to know if there already was a property for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that `_isMounted` is getting set by Vue.

Comment: You shouldn't use private properties that aren't exposed in the API as they may change and break your code in some future release.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it to search for your component if it mounted

`this.$options.components[findComponentName]`

or using `v-ref` like this one `<comp v-ref:comp-name></comp>`

and you can use it from the `$refs` object `if(this.$refs.compName)`